# How to combine combobox with list of removable drivers in c#

Tags: c#, combobox

My code is :

```
private void ListOfDrivers_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DriveInfo[] ListDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
            foreach (DriveInfo Drive in ListDrives)
            {
                if (Drive.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                {
                    ListOfDrivers.DataSource = ListDrives.ToList();
                }
            }
        }
```

I want to display the mounted removable disks in a combo box and user must choose a driver. But when I execute the above code there is no items in the combo box even though I've plugged in a removable drive. The combo box shows nothing but empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're loading the `DataSource` for the `ComboBox` in its own `SelectedIndexChanged` event. That event only fires when the selection changes, but it'll never fire because there aren't any items yet.

You could move the above code into your Form's `Load` event, so it's available right away.

Also, if you have multiple removable drives, you're only going to display the last one, since you're overwriting `DataSource` inside the `foreach` loop. I'd suggest using LINQ to filter the results:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ListOfDrivers.DataSource = 
                               DriveInfo.GetDrives()
                               .Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable)
                               .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Loop is bit wrong, I wish you could correct it. I guess op wants to filter `ListDrives` by `DriveType.Removable`. If not also setting `DataSource` inside loop makes no sense.